# recaptcha PHP validation not working i think

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, recaptcha

OK, So bear with me here, please.

I've got my HTML form code set up like this ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'clean'
     };
</script>                                   
<form method="post" action="signup-form-1.php">
    <label for="Name">Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Your Name" required="required" /><br /><br />

    <label for="Email">Email Address:</label><br />
    <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Your E-mail address" required="required" /><br /><br />

     <label for="Phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" name="Phone" id="tel" placeholder="Numbers and Hyphens allowed" required="required" /><br /><br />

    <!--<label for="Subject">Phone Number:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" /><br /><br />-->

    <label for="Age">Age:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="Age" id="Age" placeholder="How Old Are You?" required="required" /><br /><br />

    <label for="InterestedIn">What Tournament are you interested in?</label><br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="InterestedIn[]" value="op1"><p class="check1">option 1</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="InterestedIn[]" value="op2"><p class="check1">option 2</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="InterestedIn[]" value="op3"><p class="check1">option 3</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="InterestedIn[]" value="op4"><p class="check1">option 4</p>


    <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
    <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message" placeholder="Additional Information"></textarea><br /><br />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=recaptcha key 1"></script>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=recaptcha key 2" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0" title="CAPTCHA test"></iframe>
        <br />
        <label for="tswcaptcha">Copy and paste the code provided in above box here:</label><br />
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" id="tswcaptcha" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
    </noscript>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="reset-button" />

</form>
```

My recaptcha shows up, I'm able to type the words, I've got my public and private keys in the right spots and everything. So far so good.

My PHP code looks like this ....

```
<?php


$EmailFrom = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$EmailTo = "my.email@mail.com";
$Subject = 'Custom Subject Line here';
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Phone'])); 
$Age = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Age'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
$InterestedIn = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['InterestedIn'])); 


// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $Phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Age: ";
$Body .= $Age;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "InterestedIn: ";
$Body .= implode(", ", $_POST['InterestedIn']);
$Body .= "\n";


// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $Name");



// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-

equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=signup-thanks.htm\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=signup-error.htm\">";
}

?>
```

My PHP now parses the data and sends it in an e-mail format. I can receive it and I even get the checkbox options separated by a comma, everything there is ok.

THE ONLY ISSUE I'm having is that even IF the recaptcha is not filled out, the form still sends. I understand that I need to validate the recaptcha in my PHP file. The issue is that I don't know how to do that.

I'm only a web development student at this point and I'm trying something I've never tried before - we've been shown BASIC contact forms and basic PHP but we have not yet dealt with checkboxes, imploding or validation - I've figured it all out on my own so far.

Can someone out there PLEASE take a look at my code and tell me how to place the validating functions in my PHP file? Details and specifics are greatly welcome.

I've tried searching this info out on my own for the past couple of days but I still don't understand - I'm not able YET to modify the answers I find to suit my needs. I'm still learning. But I do need to do this and your help would be greatly appreciated.

Any kind souls out there willing to take pity on an eager n00b?

Comment: Please at least [format and indent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) your code blocks correctly before posting your question. It'll make it easier for us to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need the recaptcha code up top, as per [this page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php?csw=1).

Try this (untested):

```
<?php
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "your_private_key";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
    } else {

        $EmailFrom = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
        $EmailTo = "my.email@mail.com";
        $Subject = 'Custom Subject Line here';
        $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
        $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
        $Phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Phone'])); 
        $Age = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Age'])); 
        $Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
        $InterestedIn = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['InterestedIn'])); 


        // prepare email body text
        $Body = "";
        $Body .= "Name: ";
        $Body .= $Name;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Email: ";
        $Body .= $Email;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Phone: ";
        $Body .= $Phone;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Age: ";
        $Body .= $Age;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Message: ";
        $Body .= $Message;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "InterestedIn: ";
        $Body .= implode(", ", $_POST['InterestedIn']);
        $Body .= "\n";


        // send email 
        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $Name");



        // redirect to success page 
        if ($success){
          print "<meta http-

        equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=signup-thanks.htm\">";
        }
        else{
          print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=signup-error.htm\">";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem in HTML side you can use `required` attr.

Example :

```
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" required/>
```

To solve this problem in PHP side you can use isset and the other string controls

Example :

```
if(isset($_GET['recaptcha_response_field']) && $_GET['recaptcha_response_field'] != "" && strlen($_GET['recaptcha_response_field']) > 5)
```